# return to a previously visited page in a QWizard using PySide2 (Qt)

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, pyside2, qwizard

I am doing a non linear wizard in python with QWizard using PySide2 (Qt). In some instances, I want to return to previously visited pages of the wizard. However I get the following error:
`QWizard::next: Page 0 already met`

QWizard::next does not allow it
But I do want to return to it.
What is the most simple way to do this ?

Comment: If by "return to previously visited pages" you mean going backwards when the user presses "Next", I don't think it's directly possible. You may try to disconnect the `clicked` signal of the Next button and connect to a function that calls `next()` by default, or eventually call `back()` until the `currentId()` or `currentPage()` of the target page is met. Qt6 added the support for [`setCurrentId()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwizard.html#setCurrentId).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.